# Ember.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enter' of undefined on transitionTo

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I have a fairly simple Ember.js app. Inside a view I call this.transitionTo which gives me the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enter' of undefined

The error is in ember.js at line 24596, where currentState is undefined

Here are the relevant parts of my app:

```
window.Plan = Ember.Application.create({});

        Plan.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
        location: 'hash'
    });

    Plan.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    });


    Plan.Router.map(function() {
        this.route('application', { path: '/' })
        this.route('index', { path: "/:current_savings/:monthly_deposit/:time_horizon" });
    });

    Plan.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        redirect: function(){
            this.transitionTo('index', 200, 200, 200);
        }
    })

    Plan.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(params) {
            var result = this.store.find('calculation', params).then(function(data) {
                return data.content[0];
            });

            return result;
        }
    });

    Plan.CurrentSavingsTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
        focusOut: function() {
            this.transitionTo('index', 150, 200, 200);
        }
    });

    Plan.MonthlyContributionTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
        focusOut: function() {
            this.transitionTo('index', 150, 200, 200);
        }
    });

    Plan.TimeHorizonTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
        focusOut: function() {
            this.transitionTo('index', 150, 200, 200);
        }
    });

Plan.Calculation = DS.Model.extend({
    target_goal: DS.attr('number'),
    target_return: DS.attr('number'),
    expected_return: DS.attr('number'),
    downside_probability: DS.attr('number')
});

Plan.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'plan/' + window.targetReturnId
});
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

    <div>
        <div>Starting Balance: {{view Plan.CurrentSavingsTextField size="10"}}</div>
        <div>Monthly Contribution: {{view Plan.MonthlyContributionTextField size="10"}}</div>
        <div>Time Horizon: {{view Plan.TimeHorizonTextField size="10"}}</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Plan Goal: {{target_goal}}</span>
        <span>Required Return: {{target_return}}</span>
        <span>Exp Return:  {{expected_return}}</span>
        <span>Downside Probability: {{downside_probability}}</span>
        <span>Time Horizon: {{time_horizon}}</span>
    </div>

</script>
```

This response is:

```
{
   "calculations":[
      {
         "id":10,
         "target_goal":3107800.0,
         "target_return":0.089,
         "expected_return":0.0708,
         "downside_probability":0.0489
      }
   ]
}
```

The app works as expected until I focus out of the text field, then I get the error.

Ember : 1.5.1

Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a

Handlebars : 1.2.1

jQuery     : 1.11.1

Comment: Looks like that isn't all the relevant code, cause that code works.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/745/edit  What's the model look like, what's the response from the server look like?  Which adapter, serializer?  What do they look like?

Comment: @kingpin2k I am getting the undefined error in your jsbin there. Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 The `CurrentSavingsTextField` `focusOut` method is causing the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Past kingpin2k was totally wrong, I missed the statement about the transition from the view.  I apologize.

`transitionTo` from a component isn't supported (at least from any documentation I could find)

You'll want to send an action out of the component and capture it in your controller or route.

```
Plan.CurrentSavingsTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    focusOut: function() {
        this.sendAction('go', 199, 200, 201);
    }
});


Plan.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var result = this.store.find('calculation', params);
      //if you just wanted the first object
     // result.then(function(collection){
     //   return collection.get('firstObject');
     // });
        return result;
    },
  actions:{
    go: function(a, b, c){
      console.log('transition');
      this.transitionTo('index',a,b,c);
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/749/edit

Comment: Can you explain {{view Plan.CurrentSavingsTextField go='go'}}? Is that passing a reference to the controller action into the view? I guess that makes sense since the view has its own separate controller.

Comment: that's hooking up action passing from the component. it means when you call `sendAction('go')` it will be translated to the action name `go` and passed to the parent controller, then up the route tree.  It's really convenient when you have multiple components and you want them to hook up to different actions outside of the component, or if you want to ignore an action from the component, you can just not hook up to it.

Answer (score -1):

This question is quite old but it still seems unanswered as far as my googling has gone. After playing around (Ember 0.13.0) I was able to get the following code to work from inside a component:

```
this.get('_controller').transitionToRoute('index', 150, 200, 200);
```

The _ infront of controller does feel like a bit of a hack and that it shouldn't really be accessible to userland code. `get('controller')` does infact return something completely different.

I do agree navigating from a view (Component) isn't best practice, but for my use case I have a few components that drop in to a dashboard for graphing etc which this is perfect for rather than calling out to controller actions. It helps me keep everything isolated inside a single component.

Comment: I haven't used Ember in months so I'm in no position to vet this. If anyone else wants to tell me if this is correct, I'll accept it as an answer